# SQL select of users by metadata

Tags: sql

Hi I'm trying to select users  with a particular role only, using the following sql statement...

```
SELECT DISTINCT ID, u.user_login, u.user_nicename, u.user_email
FROM wp_users u, wp_usermeta m
WHERE m.meta_key = 'wp_capabilities'
AND m.meta_value LIKE '%supplier%'
ORDER BY u.user_registered
```

However, it reurns the whole table. What am I doing wrong?

PS this needs to be a SQL select as I'm doing this in myphpadmin to export the data to csv.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You might have more luck over at the Stack Exchange [Database Administrators](http://dba.stackexchange.com/) site.

Comment: @Chris_O I disagree. While this is pertinent to generic DB operations, it also does cover bits of the WordPress API as shown by kaiser's answer below.  I think it should stay.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Double-check your SQL syntax.  It sounds like you want to do a [`JOIN`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/join.html) ... But you're not building the query correctly.

It should be something more like:

```
SELECT u.ID, u.user_login, u.user_nicename, u.user_email
FROM $wpdb->users u
INNER JOIN $wpdb->usermeta m ON m.user_id = u.ID
WHERE m.meta_key = 'wp_capabilities'
AND m.meta_value LIKE '%supplier%'
ORDER BY u.user_registered
```

You have to tell the query how you're relating the user meta to the user.

Also note that I'm using `$wpdb->` rather than `wp_`.  This is important if you ever expect to use this query in a plugin on a site with a database prefix other than "wp."  If you're running things directly in SQL, though, you should switch back.

Comment: When I changed the == to = and corrected the spelling of 'capabilities' this worked a treat. Thanks EAMann! As I'm using this in phpmyadmin I dont need the $wpdb-> to specify the table prefix. But for anyone who is coding this into php its definitely the way to go!

Comment: Sorry, I wrote this quickly while debugging a bunch of .Net equality operations ... `==` works better in that world, so I put it in by mistake.  Everything's corrected above.

Comment: This was very helpful for me to find users that are woocommerce customers since that information is set in the wp_capabilities field. Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

There's a (query-)class built into core:

[`new WP_User_Query;`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_User_Query)

```
// Example
$all_subscribers = new WP_User_Query( array( 'role' => 'subscriber' ) );
```

This then allows looping through the user *objects*:

```
// Example
foreach ( $all_subscribers as $subscriber )
{
    echo $subscriber->display_name;

    // Check object:
    var_dump( $subscriber );
}
```

For further examples, or querying users by other fields, please consult the codex.